# return all IQueryable with Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I just switched from Linq to entities framework, and I'm having problems with methods that returns "all rows". I get: "The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced" error in my "service layer" that calls the data-layer.

I get an error on:

```
BookingObjectRepository _repository = new BookingObjectRepository();

public IQueryable<BookingObject> GetBookingObjects()
{
    return _repository.GetBookingObjects();
}
```

and in the "data-layer" I have:

```
BookingsystemEntities _entities = new BookingsystemEntities();

public IQueryable<BookingObject> GetBookingObjects()
    {
        return from bo in _entities.BookingObjectSet
               select bo;
    }
```

UPDATE: Filter items, they are "physically" in Filters-folder but namespace is same as the emdx file uses.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text; 

namespace BookingSystem.Data.Models
{

public static class BookingObjectFilters
{public static IQueryable<BookingObject> ByBookingObjectID(this IQueryable<BookingObject> qry, int bookingobjectID)
{
return from bo in qry
               where bo.BookingObjectID == bookingobjectID
               select bo;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system must have .NET 3.5 SP 1 or better installed, **and** your project *must* reference the System.Data.Entity assembly (look at the references node in Solution Explorer).

Answer (score 2):

Do you have

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
```

in your usings?

and

```
public IQueryable GetBookingObjects() { return _repository.GetBookingObjects(); }
```

should probably be

```
public IQueryable<BookingObject> GetBookingObjects() { return _repository.GetBookingObjects(); }
```

Hope that helps,

Dan

Comment: where shall I add that? in my repository in data layer?

Comment: Check the edit sir, noticed a problem with signature of method

Comment: http://svevarn.com/BookingObjectsService.txt
http://svevarn.com/BookingObjectRepository.txt

Comment: What namespace is BookingObject in please?

Comment: Haven't defined any except in the designer-file in the edmx file

Comment: Check namespace on the designer file in EDMX and add to the srvice layer usings.

Kindness, Dan

Comment: Now that works, but for some reason it complains about the: public IQueryable<BookingObject> GetBookingObjects(int bookingobjectID)
        {
            return _repository.GetBookingObjects().ByBookingObjectID(bookingobjectID);
        }

eventhough my "ByBookingObjectID-filter" is in same namespace

Comment: ah, you will need a reference to the EDMX namespace in the filter too!

Comment: hmm, seems like the first problem still is there :S

Comment: added a reference to service-layer and error disapeared... hope it wont cause problems later